# Detect dbms type in Entity Framework (Oracle or SQL Server)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

How can Entity Framework detect if it is created from SQL Server or Oracle by code? Is there any 
property or method which returns the source database type?

Comment: The connection string specifies the DB Provider. What are you trying to achieve? Do you have a single context that might be connecting to two different databases?!

Comment: I want to execute a custom query and syntax it depends on DBMS. so I need to know which syntax I must Choose

Comment: But why all in one context? Surely you should have a SQLContext and an OracleContext and then call them when appropriate. What in the application determines which DB you are going to call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a better way of doing this than getting the [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and checking its type.

If you create a class library solution and install the NUnit and EntityFramework nuget packages you can run the below.

```
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Diagnostics;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace efProviderChooser
{
    public class MyThing
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyThing> Things { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [Test]
        public void CanGetProvider()
        {
            var context = new MyContext();          
            var dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories
                                     .GetFactory(
                                       context.Database.Connection);

            Debug.WriteLine(dbProviderFactory.GetType());
            //gives one of 
            //System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderFactory
            //System.Data.Odbc.OdbcFactory
            //System.Data.OleDb.OleDbFactory
            //System.Data.OracleClient.OracleClientFactory
            //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory
            //this list could change!

            // here I get SqlClient
            Assert.That(dbProviderFactory.GetType().ToString().Contains("SqlClient"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Entity Framework knows it from connection being used in `DbContext` (either from connection string, because it has `Provider` part or from instance itself directly). You can get the "type" from `DbContext.Database.Connection`. I.e.:

```
DbContext.Database.Connection.GetType().Name
```

Comment: Yep, this is a quicker way at getting at that info than mine... Doh!